# Silverlight div leaves remnant of prior screen before load

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have one page with a Silverlight object on it, and many times when visiting the page, there is between .1-2 seconds where the previous screen's content is frozen inside the box where the Silverlight object should be, before Silverlight starts loading with the 1-99% progress circle.  I'm using Chrome.  It is very sloppy looking loading.  I image the problem might go unnoticed after the first cache, but is there any way to avoid this visual remnant?

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height:440px; padding-top:15px" >
    <object name="slupload" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="440px" height="100%"  >
        <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/SilverlightWebcam.xap?@nocache"/>
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.41108.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
        <param name="initParams" value="userid=@ViewBag.UserID" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.41108.0" style="text-decoration:none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
        </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the visibility of the Silverlight object with Javascript so that it appears after the page has loaded/rendered?

Comment: No, but that seems fine if it works.  I'll try a little later and let you know.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  I used $(window).load, rather than $(document).ready.  This must be common sense to Silverlight pro's, but it's new to me, and I didn't find this documented anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: +1: Have made comment an answer now you have confirmed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the visibility of the Silverlight object with Javascript so that it appears after the page has loaded/rendered.